# Json.NET SerializeObject escape values to prevent XSS

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Using Json.NET

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Property = "<script>alert('o hai');</script>" })
```

returns

```
{"Property":"<script>alert('o hai');</script>"}
```

Is it possible for the value to be escaped by SerializeObject to prevent a hostile script from executing? I'd prefer not to make changes to the object itself.

Edit: Ideally I'd like to integrate the sanitizing into the SerializeObject call without having to process the object before or after SerializeObject.

Edit: The string output from `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` is assigned to a global variable in a script block, which I believe is where the XSS issue is.

Comment: In .NET Core 3.0, `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` escapes html characters default. (See details below)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Functionality to achieve this was added in  [version 4.5.11](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2012/11/20/json-net-4-5-release-11-serialization-tracing)

This allows you to add various type of escaping to the output.

This is my LinqPad test:

```
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

    settings.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml;

    var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Property = "<script>alert('o hai');</script>" }, settings);

    Debug.Print(output);
```

outputs

```
{"Property":"\u003cscript\u003ealert(\u0027o hai\u0027);\u003c/script\u003e"}
```

Just as a disclaimer, this isn't a golden bullet to fix xss, but should help you mitigate it a bit given your example.

Comment: You made my day. This removes a lot of cruft. (Mind you if I could just get them to abandon old school ASP.NET and use Durandal we wouldn't be doing this low level nonsense...)

Comment: To do this application-wide, you can use `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings { StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml };`

Answer (score 18):

This may not be ideal but this is my solution (for now, at least):

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Property = "<script>alert('o hai');</script>" }, new HtmlEncodeStringPropertiesConverter());
```

with a simple JsonConverter that performs HtmlEncode on the value if it is a string

```
public class HtmlEncodeStringPropertiesConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(Encoder.HtmlEncode(value.ToString()));
    }
}
```

(`Encoder` is `Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder` from the AntiXSS library)

Comment: Oops, useless comment earlier.

Comment: Do you have an example for obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, settings);

Answer (score 5):

In .NET Core 3.0, `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` escapes html characters by default.

```
var text = "<script>alert('o hai');</script>";

var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { Property = text });

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output

```
// .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0
{"Property":"\u003Cscript\u003Ealert(\u0027o hai\u0027);\u003C/script\u003E"}
```

## Documentation

[How to serialize and deserialize JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#serialization-behavior) in *Serialization behavior* section says:

> The [default encoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.javascriptencoder.default?view=netcore-3.0#System_Text_Encodings_Web_JavaScriptEncoder_Default) escapes non-ASCII characters, HTML-sensitive characters within the ASCII-range, and characters that must be escaped according to [the JSON spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-7).

Please also check the remarks for [JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.javascriptencoder.unsaferelaxedjsonescaping?view=netcore-3.0#remarks) because it contains a series of remarks starting with *Unlike the Default*.

---

## I don't want to escape it

`JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping` needs to be set to turn **off** the default behavior.

```
var options = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions() { 
  Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping
};
var json2 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { Property = text }, options); 
Console.WriteLine(json2);
```

```
{"Property":"<script>alert('o hai');</script>"}
```

### `UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping`'s Documentation

[Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.javascriptencoder.unsaferelaxedjsonescaping?view=netcore-3.0#remarks) for `UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping`:

> Unlike the Default encoder, this encoder instance does not escape HTML-sensitive characters such as <, >, &. As a result, it must be used cautiously; for example, it can be used if the output data is within a response whose content-type is known with a charset set to UTF-8.
>
> Unlike the Default encoding, the quotation mark is encoded as " rather than \u0022.
>
> Unlike the Default encoding (which only allows UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin), using this encoder instance allows UnicodeRanges.All to go through unescaped.
>
> Unlike the Default encoder, this encoder instance allows some other characters (such as '+') to go through unescaped and therefore must be used cautiously.

Answer (score 4):

No, JSON.NET is a JSON serializer. It is not a XSS sanitizer. You may take a look at the [AntiXSS](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) library from Microsoft. Here's an [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx) about its usage (a little outdated but still relevant).

Comment: I tried AntiXSS but I haven't found a way to get it to not sanitize too much when processing the string returned by `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object)`. If I can get the AntiXSS encoding to run only on the property values that would probably do it.