# Json.net escape html element special character in Json serialization

Tags: json.net

I am dynamically injecting Json into page `<script>` tags but this can be problematic without the proper special character escaping in string values. JavaScriptSerializer does it correctly but I want to use Newtonsoft Json.net instead.
JavaScriptSerializer serializes like this:

```
{
    "Description": "To test escaping:\r\n\u003cscript\u003ealert(\u0027sdfg\u0027);\u003c/script\u003e"
}
```

but JsonConvert.SerializeObject does it like this:

```
{
    "Description": "To test escaping:\r\n<script>alert('sdfg');</script>"
}
```

How can I get JsonConvert.SerializeObject to serialize special characters like JavaScriptSerializer?

Comment: Does setting [`JsonSerializerSettings.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_StringEscapeHandling.htm) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26296363/3744182) by John Perrin to [Json.NET SerializeObject escape values to prevent XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10756232/3744182) meet your needs?  It seems like it should but I'm not exactly sure how `JavaScriptSerializer` escaped things, so there's a chance it isn't a perfect fit.

Comment: `StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml` works as required, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/C06nWH.